# How to zip a big folder into small files limited to 20Mb?

Tags: windows-7, zip

I'm looking for way to zip a big folder into many 20Mb files. I don't want the zip file split into smaller ones. Instead I want to group some sub files/folders into groups which is 20Mb when zipped.

If you know how to do so, please help!

*Update*

I need to use the smaller zipped files alone which are able to be unzipped alone.

My intention is to use [virustotal.com](http://virustotal.com) to scan a big folder.

Comment: Any details about operating system you're using?

Comment: @Pitto I use Windows-7

Answer (score 11):

In winzip:
Add the files to the zip either by starting up winzip and adding or drag and drop into winzip or right click on the files and winzip 'add to zip...'

Then in winzip:

Actions - Split
at the bottom of 'part size' pick 'other size' then put 20 and select mb

Done!

Comment: Staying on the free side also 7zip works perfectly :)

Comment: This will split the zip file, and we cannot use the splitted parts alone.

Comment: Omg now I understand better what you're looking for...
I just can't find any kind of solution to you problem, then :(
What about using the free and marvellous Malwarebytes Antimalware to scan the files locally?

Answer (score 9):

Letting zip do the splitting for you will be much easier to automate than trying to figure it out by yourself.  If your goal is 20MB zip files, you will have to estimate the compressed size of each file before adding it to the archive.  Is there a reason you don't want to just let zip do the splitting for you?  Here's how you'd do it with gnu zip:

```
zip -s 20m -r myzip.zip mydir
```

This will create 20MB zipped files with incremental index numbers in the filename.

Comment: Based on OP's comment to another answer, it sounds like he doesn't want zip to automatically split it because then you get a single archive which requires all files to function properly, but he wants each piece to be a complete, usable archive, independent of the others.

Answer (score 6):

What you're proposing is essentially a variation of [the Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), with the added twist that, due to file compression, you don't start off knowing how much of your 20MB "knapsack" each item will occupy.

The trivial solution, of course, would be to simply zip each file independently, but that fails to reduce the file count any, so I suspect it would not be a satisfactory solution.

If I were presented with this problem, I suppose I would start out by compressing each file individually to a temporary location (or in memory, without writing them to disk), just so that I could get an approximate compressed size for each.  With that information, it would then be possible to decide which files should be grouped together by any of the standard approaches to the Knapsack Problem and create the actual zip files.

Assuming you have a scripting language available to you and you know how to use it, I would expect this approach to be fairly straightforward to automate; doing it manually would be quite tedious if you have more than a handful of files to deal with...

Comment: can you not zip with 'no compression'? Looking at the op's "update" it seems the file format is more important than the compression.

Comment: Heh...  Good point.  I hadn't considered the use of zip as a simple archive without compressing.

Comment: @DaveSherohman So how can we do it then?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux there is a program named [zipsplit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipsplit) that does exactly this. It's part of the standard zip package.

It can be run like this:

```
zipsplit bigfile.zip -n 20000000
```

to split bigfile.zip into parts of max 20MB. And note that individual contained files will **not** be split. Thus each part can be individually unzipped. Which also means that if there is a single file that can't fit into the max part size the splitting will not be possible.

**Update:**
It seems that there are also binaries for Windows at info-zip.org, specifically in ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/zip300xn-x64.zip for Win 64.

Answer (score 3):

Not an easy prospect I'm afraid.

I recently wrote a script to gather files into subdirectories not larger than 4.3GB for easy storage on DVD, but this was all uncompressed.

Doing it with compression - now there's the challenge.  You can't predict the size of the files *after* compression - all you could do is keep adding files to the zip in descending order of size until it exceeds 20MB and then remove the last file replacing it with a smaller one until it drops below 20MB. If you exhaust all the files and it's still >20MB then just drop the last file and move on to the next zip.

Quite a tricky bit of scripting and a rather slow, painful, process.

Comment: Here my thought. Why not simply group files/folders into <=20Mb unzipped group then zip them? We do not need the .zip result files to be exactly 20Mb each.

Comment: Possible - not sure how you'd go about that in windows with scripting - I used Perl on Linux before.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I just did this with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

You need to use the "Split to Volume" option:

[image]

Comment: Cool. I'll try and back with you later.

Comment: Doesn't work for this specific scenario because the smaller zipped files can't be unzipped alone; they must be kept together.

Answer (score 2):

[Dave seemed to provide the closest programmable solution](https://superuser.com/a/266329/613335) to what OP requested. I figured out that **this could be done manually** as well, if the following assumptions are taken (this is not a pure technical problem–it is more of an *organizational* problem than technical):

1. Since the **OP requires that each zip file should be able to extract all its contents independently**, files that surpass 20 MB after zipping must be handled in one of the following ways:

   - they are not to be considered, and therefore must be separated;
   - they need to be split into 20MB volumes, as other answers suggested ([winzip](https://superuser.com/a/265317/613335), [7-zip](https://superuser.com/a/1059067/613335)), and the resulting files cannot be used independently (breaking this 1<sup>st</sup> assumption).
2. The zipped files do not necessarily need to have exactly 20MB.
3. If it is more important to have several zip files with the approximate 20MB size, then zipping can be done without compression.

By using this method with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (Windows' interface and terminal) I preserved the compression in the newly generated zip files.

Start by zipping all the files into a single zip file in an empty folder (with your desired compression method), e.g. `ALL.zip`, and open it:

1. Order the list of files and folders by clicking on the size or packed-size (compressed) column;
2. Start from the smallest sizes and select files/folders that you want to group into a zip;
3. Press the `Test` button to confirm their collective size (this considers their compression):
   [image: Test feature]
4. Press the `Extract` or `Copy` button while adding to the end of the extraction path a new folder's name (e.g.: `plu_8MB`)
5. Inside `ALL.zip` zip, delete these files you just extracted (avoiding mistaken re-extractions) and navigate to the next folder or subset of files;
6. Repeat **one** of the following:

   - steps 1 to 5 if you plan to create an independent zip file;
   - steps 1 to 3 and reuse the same folder name (step 4) until their collective sizes are approximately 20MB;
7. Once you have extracted all the contents of `ALL.zip` into independent folders, delete that zip, and [open the terminal in that folder](https://superuser.com/q/339997/613335);
8. Type:

   ```
   for /F %i in ('dir /b') do "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tzip %i.zip %i
   ```

   Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and this will generate a zip file for each folder that you just extracted.

Comment: For different parameters in the recompression, here is the [7zip syntax documentation](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/syntax.htm).

Answer (score 0):

http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2

This is an old product I found searching around the web.

It might work.
Make sure to select custom size of 20m on the right hand side of the window.