# How to open a terminal quickly from a file explorer at a folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-explorer, console, context-menu

This can be done easily in Ubuntu, just right click and open Terminal. It is very inconvenient to open `cmd.exe` then `cd` to the folder.

So, how do I open a terminal quickly from a file explorer at a folder?

Comment: @grwawity Not a duplicate: the linked question restrict to the the Context Menu, while this one is open to any other method. E.g. another solution is to type "cmd" to location bar. I'd like to add it as answer but cannot because this question is marked as duplicate…

Answer (score 121, accepted):

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **Right Click** the folder you want it opened on, and click "*open command window here*". That should do the trick!

**OR**

2. You can also type `cmd` into the Windows File Explorer address bar (use <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to focus the address bar) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the shell.

Comment: #2 is a neat trick, it’s a shame it doesn’t work (in Windows 10) for UNC paths.

Comment: #1 not working for me on Win 10. I get PowerShell.

Comment: @johnywhy you're right, it's PowerShell on Win 10. This answer on superuser seems to be the best way to restore the "open command window" via some registry edits - it also has an alternative enhancement to keep both with a new registry file: https://superuser.com/a/1202148

Comment: @sofly Maybe you can just go into Windows 10 Settings > Taskbar, and turn off "Replace command prompt with Windows PowerShell"

Comment: Number **1.** is good to open **Powershell**, number **2.** is good for **classic command line**.

Comment: I use number 2 with PowerShell with no problem?

Answer (score 9):

You can type `cmd` in Windows Explorer's location bar (which you can edit with the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>); it will open a terminal upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Personally I use a voice command in *Dragon NaturallySpeaking* that takes care of it:

[image: Dragon NaturallySpeaking commands editor]

Code:

```vb
Sub Main
    SendKeys "%d"
    Wait(0.1)
    SendKeys "cmd"
    Wait(0.1)
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is CTRL-D the correct combination to edit the address bar in Explorer, or is it ALT-D?

Comment: @music2myear  ALT-D

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This will allow you to edit the location bar address of the file explorer. Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open command prompt in current folder.

Comment: Probably need to clarify this needs done from Windows/File Explorer, which versions of Windows it works with, and confirm none of the existing answers contain this already.

Comment: I think this is the best answer about open terminal for current folder path

Answer (score 1):

You can use Andrew Richards' [Enhancing the “Open Command Prompt here” Context Menu experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience) tweak

[image: run cmd elevated]

[image: run powershell elevated]

Just import the below *.reg file (or copy from the MSDN blog above)

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Command Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


; PowerShell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"


; Ensure OS Entries are on the Extended Menu (Shift-Right Click)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have access to any Win7 machine right now i'll give you 2 answers, one that I know that works in winXP and one that I found but don't know if it works in Win7.

- WinXP Solution - Registry Option http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm
- Win7 Solution http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/27778-open-command-window-here.html

Answer (score 0):

## Update for Windows 10 when CMD was replaced by PowerShell:

For quite some time, there is a PowerShell module called [OpenHere](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module) that gives you granular options to control this functionality.

All you need is to copy paste this into PowerShell with elevated rights:

```
Install-Module -Name OpenHere; Import-Module -Name OpenHere
```

and start to explore the `Set-OpenHereShortcut` function.

### Disclosure:

I'm a developer of this module.

Comment: Incomplete answer. i don't know what this means: "start to explore the Set-OpenHereShortcut function." Also, powershell doesn't replace cmd completely. This question is about cmd, not powershell.

Comment: Get-Help Set-OpenHereShortcut. 

PowerShell does replace CMD completely but you can work with CMD shortcut if you wish. Kindly RTFD.