# How do I change "Open with Powershell" to "Open with Command Prompt" when shift-rightclicking in Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

Shift-rightclicking an empty spot in Explorer displays *"Open with PowerShell"* instead of *"Open with Command Prompt"* since the [Creators Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1703_(Creators_Update)) (2017-04). How can I get the old behaviour back where it shows *"Open with Command Prompt"*?

I tried changing the setting *"Show PowerShell instead of Command Prompt when rightclicking the Start Menu or pressing Windows + X"* to off, but that didn't change the shift+rightclick menu.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Open regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`, [take ownership of the key](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.210), add your user account full permissions and change the name of the DWORD from `HideBasedOnVelocityId` to `ShowBasedOnVelocityId` to [enable the command prompt entry again](https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2016/12/10/eingabeaufforderung-wieder-im-kontextmenue-der-windows-10-creators-update-anzeigen).

[image]

Or apply [Andrew Richards tweak to have both shown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrew_richards/2017/03/01/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience/) (cmd and PowerShell, also with entry to have elevate (running as admin) version),

[image]

[image]

by importing his .reg file (create a new txt file, paste the content and rename the file extension to reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Command Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


; PowerShell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"


; Ensure OS Entries are on the Extended Menu (Shift-Right Click)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""
```

Comment: The 2nd method in your answer is good. But for someone who has no idea what to do with the .reg, just copy the file text into a .txt file & rename the file <name>.reg & double click it to run. Even though there is error message, the operation is success

Comment: How to restore from these reg keys?

Comment: I'd rather prefer all of them to be sub menus of a single menu item. In original article there are also GIT bash items, makes default menu too cluttered.

Comment: @Pavel edit the reg you want it to have. Andrew explained it . he also has a video about it: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-176-CMD-and-PowerShell-Context-Menus

Comment: @vee delete the new entries under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\

Comment: Is it possible to change the default terminal to open? I'd like to use conEmu and have a similar context menu

Comment: @Nick change the value for the **command** entries and replace cmd.exe with any terminal you want.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me until I applied the solution to all three of these registry paths: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd`, 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`, and 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd` as directed [here](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-restore-open-command-window-here-option-in-shiftright-click-menu/)

Comment: That .reg file works like a charm.

Comment: Well, [Andrew Richards tweak to have both shown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrew_richards/2017/03/01/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience/) is now gone, "Page is Disabled" - thank you Microsoft, Windows is really so useful, it is worth every cent!

Comment: @sdaau thanks, I wrote Andrew a mail to ask his blog status.

Comment: @sdaau the blog is back online after [MSFT restored all deleted blogs](https://twitter.com/MSDNService/status/1118186707831013376)

Answer (score 36):

As a quick alternative to the other answers, you can type `cmd` on the address bar of Explorer to open a command prompt `cd`'d to the current directory. (If you are more of a keyboard person, you can use the `Ctrl + L` shortcut to focus the address bar and then type `cmd`.)

This works for `powershell` too.

Edit (2021-08-02): As @pj.dewitte pointed out, you may need to use the `.exe` extension (i.e. `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe`).

Comment: For me "cmd.exe" was needed instead of only "cmd". "powershell" works too. Great alternative for the proposed registry edits!

Comment: You're right. I guess it has something to do with the more recent versions of Windows. Thanks! Added to the answer.

Comment: I have Windows 10 21H2 and just _cmd_ works. Great tip!

Comment: Other than `Ctrl + L` there is also `Super + F4` which does nearly same, first one highlights the current content so when you start typing it replaces everything, and former does not highlight everything. Also `Super + F4` is very easy to mistake with alt f4.

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely easy to accomplish

> - In the **Taskbar and Start Menu Properties** window, go to the Navigation tab and uncheck the **Replace Command Prompt with Windows
>     PowerShell** option.
> - Click Apply for the change to take effect.
>
> [image]

Sources:

- [Replace Command Prompt With PowerShell On Power User Menu In Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/replace-command-prompt-with-powershell-on-power-user-menu-in-windows-10/)
- [Show Command Prompt or PowerShell in Win+X Power User Tasks Menu in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/chillout-room/1961-change-default-command-prompt-powershell.html)

> [image]

Additional Source:

- [Microsoft Replaces Command Prompt With PowerShell As Windows 10 Default Shell](https://fossbytes.com/powershell-replaces-command-prompt-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

To summarize all research and improving [Andrew Richards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience) registry tweak, I got rid off annoying sub-menus by utilizing single `runas` verb for legacy command prompt and implementing elevated entry for PowerShell using `Start-Process` from non-elevated instance called by `cmd.exe`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ps_uac_usr\command]
@="cmd /C powershell \"start powershell -a '-noexit -command Set-Location ''%V''' -v RunAs\""
```

- `v` flag specifies [Verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7#parameters) set to `RunAs` triggers elevation via UAC prompt;
- `a` stands for `ArgumentList` that passes `noexit` option that prevents new PS window from closing upon start and `Set-Location` option is self-explanatory;
- `%V`passes initial path for new command prompt (when file(s)/folder(s) is selected it will pass the location of item that was right-clicked on, if nothing is selected it is equal to working directory);
- note, `\` escaping double-quotes dictated by reg file syntax as line should be seen as `@="<command>"`, where `<command>` is what actually ends up in key value data;
- and the most critical part is [proper use](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) of `'` necessary to specify that first instance of PowerShell should not parse quoted contents at all and pass arguments literally while preserving set of `'` for final PowerShell to be able to ignore any rogue `&` (`%V` variable is expanded by `explorer.exe` prior to any execution, so we don't have to worry about it).

Nothing new, but it makes sense since this implementation preserves backwards compatibility. Legacy `cmd` will start even if PowerShell executable does not exist.
Combination of `runas` registry key placed directly inside `shell` key is what grants permissions. And since there may be only one such key in any unique `shell` key, hence the limitation that forced Andrew to not only use use sub-menus, but make them separate for CMD/PS instead of single sub-menu.
By using single root `runas` key for elevated `cmd.exe` explicitly and spawning other entries with PowerShell, it is possible to avoid annoying sub-menus.

So my custom `.reg` file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; CMD

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\q_cmd_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\q_cmd_usr\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\q_cmd_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\q_cmd_usr\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\q_cmd_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\q_cmd_usr\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

; CMD (Elevated)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
;"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

; PS (Elevated)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ps_uac_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ps_uac_usr\command]
@="cmd /C powershell \"start powershell -a '-noexit -command Set-Location ''%V''' -v RunAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ps_uac_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ps_uac_usr\command]
@="cmd /C powershell \"start powershell -a '-noexit -command Set-Location ''%V''' -v RunAs\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ps_uac_usr]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ps_uac_usr\command]
@="cmd /C powershell \"start powershell -a '-noexit -command Set-Location ''%V''' -v RunAs\""
```

**If possible to avoid modifications to existing entries behavior, it is much less messy to instead of taking ownership of system entries in registry, simply create own.** This should explain why I reused default entry which is missing icon and why the only difference of elevated prompt entries is a tiny shield icon. Instead of hardwiring text captions to specific language, lines like `@="@shell32.dll,-8506"` allow entries to stay localized.

Using `;` to comment/*uncomment* `"Extended"=""` line allow to unhide/*hide* respectively this entry form default right-click menu. Hidden one is still accessed by `Shift + Right Click`. In my registry file, entry for elevated cmd is show by default, rest is hidden behind Shift+RMB.

`Directory\shell` path corresponds to right click on any folder,
`Drive\shell` to system drives,
`Directory\Background\shell` to background area of working directory in Explorer window.

By my observation, entries in right-click context menu are sorted in alphanumeric order, the same as they are read from registry. This should explain names for keys in my reg file, other than that they better be pretty unique to not collide with anything possible.

Comment: Your optimized .reg is neat, thanks. But the elevated Powershell window can't change to working folder if the folder has single quote character in its name, e.g. "Oma's Nest". It would just stay at the default "C:\Windows\system32" folder. (Tested on LTSC 2019).

Comment: nmhung1985, yes, you are right, it is a limitation. Single-quote `'` has to be escaped with another one in front of it in PowerShell, so `Oma''s Nest` from your example. Interestingly enough, original .reg file version from Andrew Richards fails at this either (since command syntax is the same, only context is different), but it opens PS window to print out an error that happens to open in the current directory, which is more due to default behavior than his command itself. Hacky...

Comment: Also note that any folder name that contains a `[` will cause an error. That will be a relatively common issue. And there's a rare edge case issue where any folder name that includes a string that matches an environment variable, such as `%OS%`, will also fail.

Answer (score 2):

To hit all of the locations where Windows has changed this, you can use the following registry file after [taking ownership](https://www.howtogeek.com/77878/take-ownership-of-or-assign-full-permission-for-a-registry-key-in-windows-7/) of each key in question.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=-
```

I would just take ownership of the `[HKCR\Directory]` and `[HKCR\Drive]` keys recursively and force permission inheritance.

[image: Registry Permissions and Ownership setting]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround without admin rights (e.g. without changing registry):

WINDOWS + R: `shell:sendto` (open Explorer in the `send to` directory of the current user (or go there manually with `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`.

Create a new .bat-file with `cmd` as only text (e.g. `_cmd_here.bat`).

You can now right-click on any file in the desired directory (with or without shift) -> send to -> `_cmd_here.bat` and the command line is opened in the directory of this file.

This costs you one click (actually mouseover) more to go into the `send to` submenu and you need at least one file in the directory, but beside that I think it is a solution for the problem.

**EDIT 2023**

Another workaround is:

1. In the Windows Explorer click in the address bar (C:/Users/...) somewhere at the right side of the address so that the address is marked up in blue.
2. Don't unmark, just type `cmd` and press enter. This will open the command shell in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to replace PowerShell with CMD:

1. Open Registry Editor, simply by searching “**regedit**” on Cortana/Search or via Run (Win + R)
2. On the address bar in the Registry Editor, paste “`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`” and hit enter
3. From the sidebar, find “cmd” and right-click, then select Permissions
4. From the permissions dialog, hit Advanced
5. Hit the Change button next to the Owner field on the top of the Advanced dialog
6. In the input field, enter your username — this can also be the email address for your Microsoft Account. Hit enter after typing in your username/email
7. Back in the Permissions window, select Administrators from the top section and allow Full Control by checking the Allow check box on the dialog, then apply the changes and close the window
8. Now, delete the **DWORD** “`HideBasedOnVelocityId`” for **CMD** from the Registry Editor
9. You may need to restart the File Explorer from the task manager to see the changes in action.

---

The above method will show CMD on the context menu when your Shift + Right Click in the File Explorer. But if you want to get rid of PowerShell, you can do so by following the steps below:

1. Follow steps 1-7 from above — but change the permissions for “*PowerShell*” instead of the **CMD**.
2. Once you apply the new permissions for PowerShell, delete the DWORD “`ShowBasedOnVelocityId`” for PowerShell
3. After that, create a new **DWORD** and call it “`*HideBasedOnVelocityId*`”
4. Double click the newly created **DWORD** and change the *hexadecimal* value to “**639bc8**”
5. Once again, You may need to restart the File Explorer from the task manager to see the changes in action.

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions will restore the `Open command window here` context menu item, keeping the existing `Open Powershell window here` context menu item. Tested under Windows 10 1909.

1. Press the **Window key + R**
2. Type `regedit`. Click **OK** button
3. To the **Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your
   device?** question, click **Yes**
4. In regedit, navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd` by copying and pasting the registry path into the address bar at the top
5. Right-click on `cmd` key in the left pane > **Permissions...** > **Advanced** button
6. In the resulting window, click the **Change** hyperlink, next to **Owner:** at the top. By
   default the owner is `Trusted installer`
7. In the resulting window, enter your username and click **Check Names** button. Click the **OK** button once it has recognised your username
8. Back on the previous screen, working from top to bottom:

   - Tick **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects**
   - Click the **Enable Inheritance** button
   - Tick **Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions from this object**
   - Click **OK**
   - Click **Yes** to the **Do you wish to continue?** question
   - Click **OK** again
9. Back in `regedit`, in the central pane, right-click `HideBasedOnVelocityId` and from the context menu choose **Rename**. Rename the value to `ShowBasedOnVelocityId`
10. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd` via the address bar and repeat steps 5-9
11. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd` via the address bar and repeat steps 5-9
12. Close regedit

Note: You may have to redo some of the changes after a Windows feature update.

Comment: The only detailed answer which flawlessly works :)

Answer (score 0):

This hides powershell from the Shift-Right Click context menu and makes cmd visible.

Using a simple text editor such as Notepad, save the following code to a file with the .REG extension (e.g. `MyImport.reg`). Then double-click the saved file and follow the prompts to import it into the Registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd]
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
```

Comment: Without explaining what this does and how to use it, this is not an answer. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: done!..........

Comment: Better, however see my edit for more of what I was expecting (not all users will know how to import content into the Registry).

Comment: Does this work with a simple .reg file, **without** first taking ownership of these keys, like in the steps of https://superuser.com/a/1564678 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will add the `Open command window here` to Explorer's  right-click context menu. The script uses [RunAsTI.bat](https://github.com/AveYo/LeanAndMean) to add & remove the relevant registry values as the `TrustedInstaller` account. This obviates changing the registry keys' permissions. Run it from an elevated command window. No restart of anything required to see the change.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
OPENFILES.EXE 1>NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO You need to run this script from an elevated command prompt. Exiting. & EXIT /B 1
TITLE Configure CMD/Powershell for the Explorer SHIFT+RIGHTCLICK menu
SET REGKEYS=HKCR\Drive\shell HKCR\Directory\shell HKCR\Directory\Background\shell
FOR %%I IN (%REGKEYS%) DO SET CMD_STRING=!CMD_STRING!REG ADD %%I\cmd /v ShowBasedOnVelocityId /t REG_DWORD /d 6527944 /f ^& REG DELETE %%I\cmd /v HideBasedOnVelocityId /f ^& 
CALL :RunAsTI CMD /C "!CMD_STRING:~0,-3!"

REM https://github.com/AveYo/LeanAndMean
#:RunAsTI snippet to run as TI/System, with innovative HKCU load, ownership privileges, high priority, and explorer support  
set ^ #=& set "0=%~f0"& set 1=%*& powershell -c iex(([io.file]::ReadAllText($env:0)-split'#\:RunAsTI .*')[1])& exit /b
function RunAsTI ($cmd,$arg) { $id='RunAsTI'; $key="Registry::HKU\$(((whoami /user)-split' ')[-1])\Volatile Environment"; $code=@'
 $I=[int32]; $M=$I.module.gettype("System.Runtime.Interop`Services.Mar`shal"); $P=$I.module.gettype("System.Int`Ptr"); $S=[string]
 $D=@(); $T=@(); $DM=[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain."DefineDynami`cAssembly"(1,1)."DefineDynami`cModule"(1); $Z=[uintptr]::size 
 0..5|% {$D += $DM."Defin`eType"("AveYo_$_",1179913,[ValueType])}; $D += [uintptr]; 4..6|% {$D += $D[$_]."MakeByR`efType"()}
 $F='kernel','advapi','advapi', ($S,$S,$I,$I,$I,$I,$I,$S,$D[7],$D[8]), ([uintptr],$S,$I,$I,$D[9]),([uintptr],$S,$I,$I,[byte[]],$I)
 0..2|% {$9=$D[0]."DefinePInvok`eMethod"(('CreateProcess','RegOpenKeyEx','RegSetValueEx')[$_],$F[$_]+'32',8214,1,$S,$F[$_+3],1,4)}
 $DF=($P,$I,$P),($I,$I,$I,$I,$P,$D[1]),($I,$S,$S,$S,$I,$I,$I,$I,$I,$I,$I,$I,[int16],[int16],$P,$P,$P,$P),($D[3],$P),($P,$P,$I,$I)
 1..5|% {$k=$_; $n=1; $DF[$_-1]|% {$9=$D[$k]."Defin`eField"('f' + $n++, $_, 6)}}; 0..5|% {$T += $D[$_]."Creat`eType"()}
 0..5|% {nv "A$_" ([Activator]::CreateInstance($T[$_])) -fo}; function F ($1,$2) {$T[0]."G`etMethod"($1).invoke(0,$2)}   
 $TI=(whoami /groups)-like'*1-16-16384*'; $As=0; if(!$cmd) {$cmd='control';$arg='admintools'}; if ($cmd-eq'This PC'){$cmd='file:'}
 if (!$TI) {'TrustedInstaller','lsass','winlogon'|% {if (!$As) {$9=sc.exe start $_; $As=@(get-process -name $_ -ea 0|% {$_})[0]}}
 function M ($1,$2,$3) {$M."G`etMethod"($1,[type[]]$2).invoke(0,$3)}; $H=@(); $Z,(4*$Z+16)|% {$H += M "AllocHG`lobal" $I $_}
 M "WriteInt`Ptr" ($P,$P) ($H[0],$As.Handle); $A1.f1=131072; $A1.f2=$Z; $A1.f3=$H[0]; $A2.f1=1; $A2.f2=1; $A2.f3=1; $A2.f4=1
 $A2.f6=$A1; $A3.f1=10*$Z+32; $A4.f1=$A3; $A4.f2=$H[1]; M "StructureTo`Ptr" ($D[2],$P,[boolean]) (($A2 -as $D[2]),$A4.f2,$false)
 $Run=@($null, "powershell -win 1 -nop -c iex `$env:R; # $id", 0, 0, 0, 0x0E080600, 0, $null, ($A4 -as $T[4]), ($A5 -as $T[5]))
 F 'CreateProcess' $Run; return}; $env:R=''; rp $key $id -force; $priv=[diagnostics.process]."GetM`ember"('SetPrivilege',42)[0]   
 'SeSecurityPrivilege','SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege','SeBackupPrivilege','SeRestorePrivilege' |% {$priv.Invoke($null, @("$_",2))}
 $HKU=[uintptr][uint32]2147483651; $NT='S-1-5-18'; $reg=($HKU,$NT,8,2,($HKU -as $D[9])); F 'RegOpenKeyEx' $reg; $LNK=$reg[4]
 function L ($1,$2,$3) {sp 'HKLM:\Software\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}' 'RunAs' $3 -force -ea 0
  $b=[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("\Registry\User\$1"); F 'RegSetValueEx' @($2,'SymbolicLinkValue',0,6,[byte[]]$b,$b.Length)}
 function Q {[int](gwmi win32_process -filter 'name="explorer.exe"'|?{$_.getownersid().sid-eq$NT}|select -last 1).ProcessId}
 $11bug=($((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).BuildNumber)-eq'22000')-AND(($cmd-eq'file:')-OR(test-path -lit $cmd -PathType Container))
 if ($11bug) {'System.Windows.Forms','Microsoft.VisualBasic' |% {[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'$_")}}
 if ($11bug) {$path=$path='^(l)'+$($cmd -replace '([\+\^\%\~\(\)\[\]])','{$1}')+'{ENTER}'; $cmd='control.exe'; $arg='admintools'}
 L ($key-split'\\')[1] $LNK ''; $R=[diagnostics.process]::start($cmd,$arg); if ($R) {$R.PriorityClass='High'; $R.WaitForExit()}
 if ($11bug) {$w=0; do {if($w-gt40){break}; sleep -mi 250;$w++} until (Q); [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($(Q))}
 if ($11bug) {[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($path)}; do {sleep 7} while(Q); L '.Default' $LNK 'Interactive User'
'@; $V='';'cmd','arg','id','key'|%{$V+="`n`$$_='$($(gv $_ -val)-replace"'","''")';"}; sp $key $id $($V,$code) -type 7 -force -ea 0
 start powershell -args "-win 1 -nop -c `n$V `$env:R=(gi `$key -ea 0).getvalue(`$id)-join''; iex `$env:R" -verb runas
}; $A=$env:1-split'"([^"]+)"|([^ ]+)',2|%{$_.Trim(' "')}; RunAsTI $A[1] $A[2]; #:RunAsTI lean & mean snippet by AveYo, 2022.01.28
```

If you want to *replace* the `Open PowerShell window here` option with `Open command window here`, or you want to restore the default `Open PowerShell window here` option, having previously changed it, you can use an [enhanced version of the script](https://gist.github.com/Untitled-Document-1/8c2951ea82f835f044b6036e07d5f8e8).

Note a few benign things that will occur when you run either version of the script:

- You may see a `The system cannot find the drive specified.` message in your CMD window
- You'll probably see a few `REG` errors in the child CMD window that is created after running the script
- Once the script has completed you'll see a `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools` window. This can be safely closed, as it is just a side-effect of utilising the `RunAsTI` snippet

Answer (score -4):

In Windows 10 this is now included in the taskbar settings.

[image: Windows 10 Taskbar Settings]

Comment: "This only changes the Windows + x menu, not the "Open with" menu when shift + rightclicking an empty spot in Explorer." -nelson2tm