# Replace powershell with command prompt in "File" menu of explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, powershell

I've been successfully replace PowerShell into cmd, I also disabled powershell from context menu completely, now everytime I use shift + right click, the command prompt is shown rather than powershell.

However, I would like to know how to replace the powershell in "File" of explorer, since I disabled the context menu via `ProgrammaticAccessOnly`, the powershell in File menu also disabled.

[image: "Open windows powershell" in file menu]

This menu is useful since it provides spawning command line as administrator user, I often require this at current working directory.

Thanks!

Comment: You can follow [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1206405/how-to-restore-open-command-prompt-in-windows-explorers-file-menu-on-creators) and hope for an answer.