# Starting Windows Terminal from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-terminal

Windows Explorer has the option to open Powershell in the current folder by going to File and either selecting `Powershell` or `Powershell (administrator)`.

Is it possible to add Windows Terminal to this menu or replace the Powershell options with Windows Terminal?

Comment: Yes, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders

Comment: Related: [How to restore “Open command prompt” in Windows Explorer's File menu on Creators Update?](https://superuser.com/q/1206405/194694)